# How to get smooth scroll with Logitech mouse at 22.04

Tags: mouse, logitech, mouse-scroll

Is there any way to achieve smooth scrolling with Ubuntu 22.04+Logtech mouse?

When using Ubuntu 20.04, I was able to achieve smooth scrolling using the method on the website [here](https://rhtenhove.nl/blog/hires-scrolling-logitech/).
However, it doesn't seem to work anymore with 22.04.
I don't know what the cause is, if there is a way to achieve smooth scrolling in 22.04, please let me know.

If I can achieve smooth scrolling, I don't care using a non-Logitech mouse.

Comment: Are you using Wayland or Xorg ?

Comment: I'm using xorg. echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE show x11.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test with your specific hardware however Gnome Tweaks is able to configure mouse scrolling behaviour which might help you.

You can install [Gnome Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) from the software centre or via `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

You can then go to the "Keyboard & Mouse" section and experiment with the different "Acceleration Profile" options:

[Gnome tweaks - mouse acceleration profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMwGK.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I installed Tweak and change "Acceleration Profile".
But There is no effect at all.